# How can i trim a url in react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

How can I trim the below URL using javascript in react native? this is the URL

"https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/industry/banking/finance/banking/is-indias-current-banking-crisis-just-old-wine-in-a-new-bottle/articleshow/71451268.cms"

I need to trim this to `economictimes.indiatimes.com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this.

```js
url = "https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/industry/banking/finance/banking/is-indias-current-banking-crisis-just-old-wine-in-a-new-bottle/articleshow/71451268.cms"
var arr = url.split("/");
console.log(arr[2]);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this

```js
const url = "https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/industry/banking/finance/banking/is-indias-current-banking-crisis-just-old-wine-in-a-new-bottle/articleshow/71451268.cms";

const result = new URL(url).host;
console.log(result); // prints "economictimes.indiatimes.com"
```

You can see more about the `URL` interface [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL)

Answer (score 0):

```js
url = "https://economictimes.indiatimes.com/industry/banking/finance/banking/is-indias-current-banking-crisis-just-old-wine-in-a-new-bottle/articleshow/71451268.cms"

console.log(url.split("//")[1].split('/')[0]);
```

Try this!